# C++ what is the difference between class pointer to a new class vs pointer to a class object?

Tags: c++, class, pointers

What is the difference between these two class initializers? 

`myClass myObject;
myClass *myPointer1;
myPointer1 = &myObject;`

and

`myClass *myPointer2 = new myClass;`

If the first pointer is just a pointer to a class object, where does the second pointer point to?

Comment: Good reading in that, but Stack and Heap are implementation details. They may not exist.

Comment: I'm sure that OP is writing for a system where stack and heap do exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myPointer1` points to an object with automatic storage duration. As such, `myPointer1` does not *own* the object it points to, but is simply a means of accessing that object. On the other hand, `myPointer2` points to an object with dynamic storage duration, and not only is `myPointer2` used to access the object, but it also needs to be used to `delete` the object later in order to avoid memory leaks.

One often says that `myPointer1` points into "the stack" while `myPointer2` points into "the heap", reflecting common implementation strategies for automatic and dynamic storage duration, respectively.

You cannot tell whether a pointer points to an object of automatic storage duration or an object of dynamic storage duration just by examining its value. You should use smart pointer objects (`std::unique_ptr<myClass>` and so on) to avoid memory leaks.